# Convert the seconds since "midnight 1904-1-1" to a date-time string

Tags: c++, c++11, time

In some multimedia metadata, there may be date-time in seconds since
midnight, Jan. 1, 1904, in UTC time.

As I know, the date time function is normally based on 1970-1-1 midnight in C/C++ standard library, at least in Visual C++, is there a function in C/C++/Win32-API to convert the seconds since "1904-1-1 midnight" to a date time string, like as "hh:mm:ss MM. dd, yyyy" or other format string or a structure like as "struct tm"?

```
struct tm
{
    int tm_sec;   // seconds after the minute - [0, 60] including leap second
    int tm_min;   // minutes after the hour - [0, 59]
    int tm_hour;  // hours since midnight - [0, 23]
    int tm_mday;  // day of the month - [1, 31]
    int tm_mon;   // months since January - [0, 11]
    int tm_year;  // years since 1900
    int tm_wday;  // days since Sunday - [0, 6]
    int tm_yday;  // days since January 1 - [0, 365]
    int tm_isdst; // daylight savings time flag
};
```

**Solution#1:**

```
int main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME systm;
    memset(&systm, 0, sizeof(systm));

    systm.wYear = 1904;
    systm.wMonth = 1;
    systm.wDay = 1;

    FILETIME filetm;
    if (SystemTimeToFileTime(&systm, &filetm) == FALSE){
        printf("Failed to convert system time to file-time.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    ULARGE_INTEGER nanoSeconds;
    nanoSeconds.HighPart = filetm.dwHighDateTime;
    nanoSeconds.LowPart = filetm.dwLowDateTime;

    nanoSeconds.QuadPart += 3600ULL * 10000000; // add 1hour based on 1904/1/1 midnight

    filetm.dwHighDateTime = nanoSeconds.HighPart;
    filetm.dwLowDateTime = nanoSeconds.LowPart;

    if (FileTimeToSystemTime(&filetm, &systm) == FALSE){
        printf("Failed to convert file-time to system time.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("New system time by adding 1 hour: %d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d\n", 
        systm.wYear, systm.wMonth, systm.wDay, 
        systm.wHour, systm.wMinute, systm.wSecond, systm.wMilliseconds);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
New system time by adding 1 hour: 1904-01-01 01:00:00.000
```

**Solution#2:**

With @Howard Hinnant's date.h, it can also solve this issue, please see the sample code provided by him https://stackoverflow.com/a/49733937/3968307

Comment: No, there's no such function in the C or the C++ library. But this does not appear to be complicated. Date math has been a solved issue a long time ago. We can easily figure out how many days there are in a particular year, how many seconds there are in each day, and how many milliseconds too. Based on that, this is a fairly simple calculation. I'm prety sure (I hope) that these kinds of questions are routine homework assignments in every intermediate level computer programming course.

Comment: You simply have to precalculate the number of seconds between your 1-1-1904 and 1-1-1970 and then re-base your date.

Comment: you can use std::chrono from the c++11 standard to create a `time_point` at 1904-1-1 midnight then add the seconds to it

Comment: How good does it need to be? Does it need to handle leap seconds for example?

Comment: Check this out https://gist.github.com/t3hk0d3/6186590

Comment: Unix timestamps are signed, so 32 bit values go back to december 1901. The Win32 API on the other hand uses a date format which goes back to 1601. See [SYSTEMTIME and FILETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms724950(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @KarstenKoop: The unix-epoch starts 1970-01-01. And not all systems use `int32_t`. On 64 bit systems, typically `int64_t` is used.

Comment: @KarstenKoop thanks, your suggestion is good for me, I have tried it, and it works well! Please see the solution#1 in the original question.

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite std::chrono *time_point* is also based on 1970-1-1 midnight, it can't create a time at 1904-1-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a good time to use [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html):

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string
convert(std::int64_t seconds_since_1904)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    constexpr auto offset = sys_days{January/1/1970} - sys_days{January/1/1904};
    return format("%T %m.%d, %Y", sys_seconds{seconds{seconds_since_1904}} - offset);
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << convert(3'606'124'378) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
13:12:58 04.09, 2018
```

### Update

The above code will port to C++20 (when it ships) by:

- Change `#include "date/date.h"` to `#include <chrono>`
- Change `using namespace date;` to `using namespace std;`
- Change `"%T %m.%d, %Y"` to `"{:%T %m.%d, %Y}"`

Comment: I try to run your sample code, but it failed to compile in my environment with VS2015, the error message like as: error C2127: 'date::nanyear': illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression

Comment: VS2015 is very weak on `constexpr`.  Try making the type of `offset` `const` instead of `constexpr`.  It makes the function a bit less efficient.  Upgrading to VS2017 will fix that I believe.

Comment: Ah, a `constexpr` snuck into date.h on me.  Thanks for the bug report!  I'll get that fixed right away.  In the meantime, if in date.h you change `constexpr year nanyear{-32768};` to `CONSTDATA year nanyear{-32768};`, that will get it running on VS2015.

Comment: Yes, after changing `constexpr auto offset` to `auto offset`, and change `constexpr year nanyear{-32768}` to `CONSTDATA year nanyear{-32768}`, it works in VS2015!

Comment: Great!  I've fixed the github repo.

Answer (score 3):

As you can easily calculate with any available spreadsheet application in your system, the difference in seconds between those two timestamps (assumed both are in UTC time) the difference in seconds from `1/1/1904` to `1/1/1970` is `2,082,844,800 sec.`  So the conversion function from a **unix timestamp** to your time, consists in adding `2082844800` to the unix timestamp you receive from any of the time functions.  In case you want to pass back from a timestamp in your time to unix timestamp, then subtract that fixed value from your timescale.  Beware that that number does not fit in a `signed int` so you must use probably a 64bit number to manage properly all those timestamps.  Worse if you want to use nanoseconds resolution.

I don't guess the reason of using that strange epoch timestamp, but to illustrate a practical and in use application of such differences, there's a timestamp in internet that uses an epoch close to that,  that is the NTP (Network Time Protocol) timestamp, that is based on 1/1/1900 epoch and has a resolution of `1/2**32 sec.` that is around `232 ps.` for a specification of this protocol, see [RFC-5905](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905)

Answer (score 1):

The time problem here practically begs you to write your own code for it. The year 1900 is an exception since it is divisible by 4 but still is not a leap year, so by starting in 1904 you can avoid that particular exception and use the fact that there are 1461 days in every four-year period starting with 1904.